# How to have two versions of Nativescript co-exist?

Tags: nativescript

Can I have two versions of Nativescript co-exist.

Switch between pre 7 and 7+

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `npx` to run multiple versions of nativescript. You should have it by default if you are running node 5.2 or higher. To run different versions of nativescript apart from the one that is globally installed, you can run the following commands:

```sh
// to create a new project with nativescript v6.5
npx nativescript@6.5 create newproject

// to run with nativescript v6.5
npx nativescript@6.5 run ios
```

And to use the globally installed nativescript cli, you can continue using the regular nativescript cli commands (without npx) - `ns run ios`/`ns create newproject`

Comment: How do I add the new CLI locally? Or better yet, how can I get my current global CLI (6.x) to be local and then install the new CLI globally. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to run all your commands prefixed with `npx nativescript@version-number` instead of `tns` to use a specific nativescript version. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlRdGPAqWl8) is a link that goes more in depth in how you can do that